# self-hosted github runner will not execute actions on a LABEL

Tags: github

I want to learn how to use a self-hosted github runner with labels.  I installed a self-hosted github runner on a server and assigned it the label `prj1`.  I then made a github project and included this `.github/workflows/deploy.yml` file.

```
name: Environment

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  p1:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - run: echo "The job was automatically triggered by a ${{ github.event_name }} event." >> deploy-log.txt
```

When I push to master branch, my self-hosted github runner says SUCCESS.  This is perfect so far.

Then I changed my `.github/workflows/deploy.yml` to include a label like this:

```
name: Environment

on:
  push:
    types: [prj1]
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  p1:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - run: echo "The job was automatically triggered by a ${{ github.event_name }} event." >> deploy-log.txt
```

Then I pushed to master.  But the github runner does not show any indication it detected anything.  The github website actions says "This check was skipped". So then I tried this:

```
name: Environment

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  p1:
    if: ${{ github.event.label.name == 'prj1' }}
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
      - run: echo "The job was automatically triggered by a ${{ github.event_name }} event." >> deploy-log.txt
```

Again, when i push changes to master, the git hub runner does not show any indication it detected anything. The github website actions says "This check was skipped".

How do I get my self-hosted runner to deploy a project only on jobs with label `prj1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FOund the answer on : https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/using-self-hosted-runners-in-a-workflow#using-custom-labels-to-route-jobs

Basically I can use the `runs-on` to specify which label.  SO my yml file looks liek this now

```
name: Environment

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  p1:
    runs-on: prj1
    steps:
      - run: echo "The job was automatically triggered by a ${{ github.event_name }} event." >> deploy-log.txt
```

This means on self-hosted github runners tagged with prj1 will run the job.